# common storage for webapp and android app

Tags: android, web-applications

Background:
I am working on a webapp using Jquery, HTML5 and PHP and I have created Android Wrapper application using webview to link my webapp as android app.

Objective: 
I want to use push notifications for wrapper application so that I can inform targeted user about updates or news.

Issue: 
I am able to get the deviceid/registration id of phone using 3rd party push notification api called PARSE but I want to link that deviceid/registrationid to the login user of my web application.

My idea was to save deviceid/registrationid in a common storage of android and when user logs in to my webapp then get the device id for that common storage and save in session to use it for sending push notifications.

Questions:
1. Is there is anyway I can link deviceid/registrationid to user login?
2. Is there a common storage (like localstorage) where I can save the id and then webapp can grab from there?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to access your back end database with authentication of user as id of their device.

```
         If so then you can achieve it as " Initially when you are 
  calling push notification function and register device for 
  push notification service at that time you casn store that 
  device id in your local database also as user id.


       So whenever user will start your application and 
  it will register device for push notification you just 
  need to check weather that device id is available or 
  not (As if user re install app) and insert in database.
```

Hope you can understand what i want to say....

Comment: Thanks for your response. My issue is that after registering user where to store the registrationid/deviceid so that my webapp can use it. This is because webapp can be used by any user and I need to map the login user with the deviceid/registrationid stored on android. Can my webapp access local database of android?